# where tag outside where only the first one takes effect

Tags: mybatis

code like this：

```
<select id="findByCondition" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
    select * from vip_vkg_entity_product
    <where>
        <if test="condition.isDeleted != null">
            and is_deleted = #{condition.isDeleted}
        </if>
        <if test="condition.name != null and condition.name != ''">
            and name like CONCAT('%',#{condition.name},'%')
        </if>
    </where>
    <choose>
        <when test="condition.sortField != null and condition.sortField != '' and condition.sortOrder != null and condition.sortOrder != ''">
            order by ${condition.sortField} ${condition.sortOrder}
        </when>
        <when test="condition.name != null and condition.name != ''">
            order by ABS(LENGTH(`name`) - LENGTH(#{condition.name}))
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            order by update_time desc
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</select>
```

Then the second if tag can work, but the second when tag doesn't work.
Console result like this:
[image]

If I move the second when tag to the top, then it works.
Code like this:
[image]
Console result like this:
[image]

So, is it MyBatis's bug?

Answer (score 0):

It is not mybatis bug. The problem is that in your case conditions in `choose` are not mutually exclusive.

Her the problem is that the condition of the first `when` evaluates to `true` and it is used. `when` conditions are evaluated top to bottom so when you change the order you get the result you expect.

To fix the issue you need to make conditions in the `when` mutually exclusive or pay attention to the order of the conditions if they do overlap like in your case.